# Is there a way to save Netbeans window/tab group states?

Tags: netbeans

I have dozens of files open in Netbeans, tiled neatly and organized in tab groups. If Netbeans crashes, I lose the current state of which files I have open, how they're tiled, and what tab groups. Similarly, if the network has a hiccup or goes down, and I lose my mounts, Netbeans will discard all the aforementioned state information.

If I could just export that information to a file, or find the file on disk that contains state information (if such a thing exists), I could avoid the headache of having to re-open all my previously open files and re-tile them and organize them into tab groups. It's a real pain when you have 50+ open files and lose them. :-(

Ideally it would be nice if that information was saved in the Netbeans project files.

Answer (score 7):

Use Window -> Document Groups functionality

Answer (score 1):

You could use "project groups". See main menu `File -> Project group`. 
The open files are automatically saved too.

Answer (score -1):

Reset windows property

TOP menu Window >> Reset Windows